# How to reload config with ansible docker_container module?

Tags: docker, ansible, haproxy

I am trying to accomplish `docker kill -s HUP <container>` in Ansible but it looks like the options I try always restart the container or attempt to instead of reloading the config.

Running the following command allows me to reload the configuration without restarting the container:

`docker kill -s HUP <container>`

The Ansible `docker_container` docs suggest the following options:

> `force_kill`           Use the kill command when stopping a running
>   container.
>
> `kill_signal`          Override default signal used to kill a running
>   container.

Using the `kill_signal` in isolation did nothing.

Below is an example of what I hoped would work:

```
- name: Reload haproxy config
  docker_container:
    name: '{{ haproxy_docker_name }}'
    state: stopped
    image: '{{ haproxy_docker_image }}'
    force_kill: True
    kill_signal: HUP
```

I assumed overriding `force_kill` and `kill_signal` would give me the desired behaviour. I have also tried setting *state* to 'started' and `present`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: So you specified `state: stopped`, but Ansible "*restarts the container or attempts to*"? Or what is this question about?

Comment: My configuration was just one example of what I have tried.

Comment: How does your comment explain anything?

Comment: @kaizenCoder your task works fine. Does the same as 'docker kill -s HUP <container>' command.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the same with an haproxy docker instance to reload the configuration. The following worked in ansible 2.11.2:

```
handlers:
  - name: Restart HAProxy
    docker_container:
      name: haproxy
      state: stopped
      force_kill: True
      kill_signal: HUP
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a simple shell `command`, which runs whenever the docker-compose file has my service:

```
---
- hosts: pis
  remote_user: pi
  tasks:
    - name: Get latest docker images
      docker_compose:
        project_src: dc
        remove_orphans: true
        pull: true
      register: docker_compose_output
    - name: reload prometheus
      command: docker kill --signal=HUP dc_prometheus_1
      when: '"prometheus" in ansible_facts'
    - name: reload blackbox
      command: docker kill --signal=HUP dc_blackbox_1
      when: '"blackbox" in ansible_facts'
```

### Appendix

I found some examples using GitHub advanced search, but they didn't work for me:

https://github.com/search?q=kill_signal%3A+HUP+docker+extension%3Ayml&type=Code

An example:

```
- name: Reload HAProxy
  docker_container:
    name: "haproxy"
    state: started
    force_kill: true
    kill_signal: HUP
```